# Send Flash message from android app

Tags: android

I am able to locate any API which can be used to send flash message from one android mobile to other mobile.
e.g I have two emulators running in my PC.I want to develop an app which allows me to send flash messages from one emulator another emulator.I am able to send sms successfully using SMSManager.
But I am not able to send flash message.

Please Help..

Comment: define `flash message`

Comment: Kind of a popup with ok and cancel buttons.

Comment: you want to have an android device display a popup?

Comment: Yaa ..Say i have two mobiles.I want to send popup message from one mobile to other mobile

Comment: you'll need an application on both devices, and possibly a server to carry the message between the 2. If you have no idea how to do that, I suggest you start by something simpler.

Comment: Can u provide me with some link wherein i can get some help regarding this